# Could I use Cython with 3rdparty pure python library?

Tags: python

I'm using Python to develop a commercial software.
But I don't want to offer source to my clients.

I knew that Cython can complie my code to binary.

But could I use Cython with 3rdparty pure python library(I mean those libraries written in pure Python)?

Comment: Cython does not compile to bytecode (`pyc` files). Are you sure you're talking about Cython? If so, you may want to re-do your research.

Comment: I knew it, and it seems that mentioning it will make you misunderstand my question.Ok, i will
edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Cython compiles to .pyd (not pyc), which is basically a dll.  In theory it should work with any python code, including 3rd party libraries, but there's no guarantee (see the first comment below).  You'd also better check the licenses of the libraries you intend to use though, to make sure they don't prohibit distributing as closed source.

Your other option is something like [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), both of which I think compile to binary.  I've never really inspected the files they produce though so you'll need to check up on that.

Comment: There *are* incompabilities with CPython, including bugs, and there are limitations that might show.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction.  I was just going by what they advertise, I haven't used it before.  I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: I just want to encode my code using Tornado without encoding Tornado.